# preg_match to match number csv format and capture each number?

Tags: php, regex, csv, preg-match

I want to use preg_match to parse '123,456,789,323' and only capture each number into arrray $m.

My php codes:

```
preg_match("/^(\d+)(?:,(\d+))*?$/",'123,456,789,323',$m));
print_r($m);
```

This is how I interpret my regexp:

```
^:              Begin of line
1st (\d+):      Capture 1st number
,(\d+):         Match pattern 'a command then a number'.
(?:,(\d+))*?:   Match zero or more [using *] of above pattern but don't
                  capture whole pattern [using ?:] instead only capture
                  the number [using (\d+)]. Lastly, match pattern 
                  nongreedy [using last ?]
$:              Match end of line.
```

But I get this output:

```
Array
 (
     [0] => 123,456,555,789,323
     [1] => 123
     [2] => 323
 )
```

What I want is:

```
Array
 (
     [0] => 123,456,555,789,323
     [1] => 123
     [2] => 456
     [3] => 789
     [4] => 323
 )
```

I thought (...)* is too greedy, so I use (...)*?. But it doesn't approve the output. What do I miss?

PS: I want to know how can regexp do this rather than use other way e.g. explode().

Comment: you want to get the number after comma? and store it in an array?

Comment: Why not use explode instead?

Comment: When repeating a capturing group only the last time it is matched is actually stored. Consider the use of [`\G`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). Don't use regex if it's not absolutely necessary, use a proper csv-library or for these simple cases use a split.

Comment: Why not use `preg_match_all("/(\d+)/", '123,456,789,323', $m);`

Comment: How to close my own question?

Comment: _How to close my own question?_ - You'd better answer your own question (perhaps citing the comment which made you wish to close). Even an answer that states "regex is not useful here" can be helpful.